# Google Sheets Adaptive list?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-sheets, logic, formula

So first let me explain what I have. I have 1 main sheet and 7 category sheets. Each category sheet has a list of items with its category type on the cell next to it.

like this:

```
 ___________________
| item1 | Category1 |
| item2 | Category1 |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

I will be adding and deleting items from these lists so I want the main sheet to be adaptive. I am not advanced enough to use app scripts and formulas don't use for loops so is there some work around?

I originally wrote this formula and quickly realized it didn't work due to it changing the cell number to the cell its in.

```
if(Equips!$A18,Equips!$A18,
   if(Mounts!$A18,Mounts!$A18,
     if(Music!$A18,Music!$A18,
       if(Emotes!$A18,Emotes!$A18,
         if(Minions!$A18,Minions!$A18,
           if(Furniture!$A18,Furniture!$A18,
             if(Misc!$A18,Misc!$A18,
               "Error"
)))))))
```

I had an idea on how to use for loops to have it count how many cells have data and output that many cells and their data but I forgot it due to getting sleepy at this point. Thank you for your help!

Example to clarify:
So say equips has 5 items.
The main sheet would display the 5 items.
Mounts then has 4 items.
On the main sheet underneath the 5 equips the 4 mounts would show up,
but say I go to the equips page and add a 6th equip. The main page would update automatically by detecting that the 6th slot in equips sheet contains data and add the 6th equip pushing the 4 mounts down.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
=query({Equips!A:A;Mounts!A:A;Music!A:A},"select * where Col1<>'' ")
```

if you mix text and number, the solution will be

```
=query({arrayformula(to_text(Equips!A:A));arrayformula(to_text(Mounts!A:A));arrayformula(to_text(Music!A:A))},"select * where Col1<>'' ")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1438PfGc9B7cJowp_YDo4v7Z-f9rVYV0n99Q-iWTstzY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you that works wonders! I did notice it breaks if I enter a number. Is there a way to fix that? also do you think you could do me the honor of explaining how this works? I would like to understand for the future

Comment: ok, I have updated the solution to transform all data into text